# Sending email in Django throws Address family not supported by protocol exception

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, sockets, django-email

I'm sending emails using Django version 2.2 and have tested it on the local machine and it works. But the same code throws `[Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol` exception.

I also couldn't find any solution online.
I have rechecked my code and there is nothing wrong in it. 
I'm using google smtp server with app_password.
Below are Details.
settings.py file

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "*******@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "app_password"
```

Email Sending Function

```
subject = 'Account Password reset mail'
ctx = {
  "user" : self.user,
  "website" : settings.WEBSITE_NAME,
  "site_url" : settings.WEBSITE_URL,
}
msg = render_to_string('login/forgot_password_email.html',ctx)
from_email = settings.WEBSITE_ADMIN_EMAIL
to_email = [self.cleaned_data.get('email'),]
result = send_mail(subject, '', from_email, to_email, fail_silently=False, html_message=msg) 
return result
```

I even try to login to server through SSH and execute through the shell but returns the same error.

```
>>> from django.core.mail import send_mail
>>> res = send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.',  'example@gmail.com',  ['example@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/y6d62pncrpga/virtualenv/public_html/django/app2/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 60, in send_mail
    return mail.send()
  File "/home/y6d62pncrpga/virtualenv/public_html/django/app2/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 291, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/home/y6d62pncrpga/virtualenv/public_html/django/app2/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 103, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/home/y6d62pncrpga/virtualenv/public_html/django/app2/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 63, in open
    self.connection = self.connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
  File "/opt/alt/python37/lib64/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/opt/alt/python37/lib64/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 336, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/opt/alt/python37/lib64/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 307, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "/opt/alt/python37/lib64/python3.7/socket.py", line 727, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/opt/alt/python37/lib64/python3.7/socket.py", line 711, in create_connection
    sock = socket(af, socktype, proto)
  File "/opt/alt/python37/lib64/python3.7/socket.py", line 151, in __init__
    _socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
OSError: [Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol
```

[image: Address family not supported by protocol Error]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: That error would imply that the SMTP hostname resolved to an IP address that is not supported by the OS, ie resolved to an IPv4 address when IPv4 is not installed/enabled, or resolved to an IPv6 address when IPv6 is not installed/enabled.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau how can I enable IPv4 or IPv6 in shared hosting

Comment: I can't answer that, I was merely commenting on what the error message means. You might try replacing `"smtp.gmail.com"` with one of Gmail's public IP addresses (173.194.76.109, 2a00:1450:400c:c00::6c, etc. Gmail has quite a number of IPv4 addresses) to help eliminate any networking problems. It might just be a DNS issue on the server your script is running on.

Comment: @PavanBaddi have you solved this? I am having the same issue. Can't find the answer anywhere